# Sharpie pod bind: unable to parse target sdk

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, tvos, objective-sharpie

I am creating an Appletvos project in c# using Xamarin and I need to use the VLCKit library, I tried using cocoapod and sharpie to create this project but I Have an error on the

```
sharpie pod bind
```

it correctly create a build directory with the file of my VLCKit but after it say

```
Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

error: unable to parse target SDK from platform in Podfile
```

I don't understand since the command

```
pod install
```

worked correctly.

this is my podfile:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
target 'ObjectiveSharpieIntegration' do
  platform :tvos, '11.2'
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'TVVLCKit-unstable', '3.0.0a50'
end
```

this Is how my terminal look like

```
   Berthiers-MacBook-Air:project berthierhadrien$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing TVVLCKit-unstable (3.0.0a24)
Generating Pods project
Skipping User Project Integration
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
Berthiers-MacBook-Air:project berthierhadrien$ sharpie pod bind VLC_Binder
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/sharpie-build

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

Write auxiliary files
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.hmap
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-project-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-generated-files.hmap
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-all-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64
write-file /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.LinkFileList

CompileC /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.o Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=137 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu11 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/sharpie-build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/sharpie-build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mtvos-version-min=11.2 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunguarded-availability -fembed-bitcode-marker -iquote /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Release-appletvos/include -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/Headers/Public/TVVLCKit-unstable -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Release-appletvos -F/Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/TVVLCKit-unstable/TVVLCKit-binary -isystem /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/Headers/Public/TVVLCKit-unstable -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.dia -c /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.m -o /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration-dummy.o

Libtool /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Release-appletvos/libPods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.a normal arm64
    cd /Users/berthierhadrien/project/Pods
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs"
    export TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.2
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Release-appletvos -filelist /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Pods.build/Release-appletvos/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.LinkFileList -framework Foundation -o /Users/berthierhadrien/project/build/Release-appletvos/libPods-ObjectiveSharpieIntegration.a

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

error: unable to parse target SDK from platform in Podfile
```

Do you know a way to fix this or how to create the bind project I need?

(also can anyone tell me if the instruction for an IOS library and TVOS library are the same I only found documentation for IOS)

(also Can I use IOS, MACOS library in TVOS project in C# using Xamarin)

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your Sharpie command line in terminal?

Comment: I added it in my post, is that what you needed ?

Comment: No , just the Sharpie command which you input .

Comment: Well I tried  `sharpie pod init tvos TVVLCKit-unstable` but then the `sharpie pod bind VLCBinder` didn't work because it didn't recognize the platform ( it was missing from the pod file) so I changed my pod file , run `pod install` and then `sharpie pod bind VLC_Binder` and It created a build dir but failed to create the bind.

Comment: tvos  named  appletvos here, try `sharpie pod init appletvos TVVLCKit-unstable`

Comment: Did you finally find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I didn't find this until I end up with the same issue.

It took me a while to figure out, but I got it thanks to the clue of the error message.

What's happening here is Objective Sharpie **trying to get a platform SDK from the Podfile**.
So, following [CocoaPods Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform) **at the end of your Podfile**, just add:

```
platform :ios, '14.5' //14.5 or whatever
```

Now run again

```
sharpie pod bind
```

And if everything went good, it should output at the end

```
Binding...
  [write] ApiDefinitions.cs
  [write] StructsAndEnums.cs
```